# Can you use a video as a background css?

Tags: css

I am looking to load a video like how I would a background-image in the CSS. The reason behind this is so I can customise more display options of the video, like how I could an image in the CSS. My problem of loading the video using video and source tags is that I cannot change the styling as much as I desire.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the background video?

Comment: @Architect, thanks for replying. Basically the size of the video I have is 1000px by 300px. I was hoping to set the video as the background-image so I could then use background-size to cover the div which in this case is; width: 50%; and height: 100%;

Comment: No you can not do that. There may be ways to achieve what you want using a video tag but you need to show us your HTML and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Turnip, is there any way using Javascript this is possible?

Comment: I posted an answer, try it like that.

Comment: Another technique would be to convert the video to .gif format(animation). And than use that .gif file just like an image. kindda hack but I think it'll work... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container video {
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="your_video_url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="your_video_url.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</div>
```

Let me know if this worked.